# Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My intent of the query is to return relations between two of multiple nodes or the selected portions of the graph as a subgraph. 
I'm getting an error message when running the query below:

```
with ['社会主义现代化建设', '中国共产党中央委员会', '香港', '依法治国', '澳门', '台湾同胞', '改革开放', '春节（中国传统节日）', '习近平', '中华人民共和国中央军事委员会', '全面深化改革', '中华人民共和国主席', '人民大会堂（1960年营口卷烟厂注册卷烟品牌）', '中国共产党中央委员会总书记', '团拜会'] as value_list
match (n:Node) 
where n.value in value_list
with collect(n) as result
unwind result as source
unwind result as target

match paths = shortestPath((source)-[*1..3]-(target)) 
with paths limit 20000
return paths
```

And I get this message:

> Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed
>   Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: The shortest path
>   algorithm does not work when the start and end nodes are the same.
>   This can happen if you perform a shortestPath search after a cartesian
>   product that might have the same start and end nodes for some of the
>   rows passed to shortestPath.
>
> If you would rather not experience this
>   exception, and can accept the possibility of missing results for those
>   rows, disable this in the Neo4j configuration by setting
>   `cypher.forbid_shortestpath_common_nodes` to false. If you cannot
>   accept missing results, and really want the shortestPath between two
>   common nodes, then re-write the query using a standard Cypher variable
>   length pattern expression followed by ordering by path length and
>   limiting to one result.

I don't have this line in my neo4j config file:

```
cypher.forbid_shortestpath_common_node=false
```

Suggestions on how to work around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

success！！only add  `where source<>target`

```
PROFILE
with ['社会主义现代化建设', '中国共产党中央委员会', '香港', '依法治国', '澳门', '台湾同胞', '改革开放', '春节（中国传统节日）', '习近平', '中华人民共和国中央军事委员会', '全面深化改革', '中华人民共和国主席', '人民大会堂（1960年营口卷烟厂注册卷烟品牌）', '中国共产党中央委员会总书记', '团拜会'] as value_list
match (n:Node) 
where n.value in value_list
with collect(n) as result
unwind result as source
unwind result as target
match paths = shortestpath((source)-[*0..3]-(target)) 
where source<>target
with paths limit 20000
return paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just add the line `cypher.forbid_shortestpath_common_node=false` to the neo4j.config file.